# One html element get overlapped by another. How to fix it?

Tags: html, bootstrap-4

Why my html element get overlapped by another? At medium and large screen it gets displayed properly but at small screen it get overlapped.

I am using bootstrap.

Please see the screenshots. Here I am giving three screenshots. The first one is seen OK. The blue background is the parent div (`<section id="prime-content">`) and the rest are childs.

I need help for solving this. I am newbie. I am learning to ask question in this platform. Should I give the html code?

**CSS:**

```
#prime-content{
    background-color: blue;
    height: 750px;
}
.pc-header{
    background-color: #FFFF00;
    width: 100%;
    padding: 30px;
    text-align: center;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
}
.pc-header h2{
    color:#000;
    float: center;
    z-index: 3;
}
.p-content{
    background-color:#fff;
}
```

**Screenshots:**

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Share your HTML code

Comment: OK. I am adding my html code inside the body of my question.

Comment: Share your code in plnkr so we can figure out what is the problem.

Comment: upload css with html

Comment: You need to provide a [mcve]

Comment: @PrashanthOlekar — Code should be shared *in the question*, not just linked to. Stackoverflow has supported [inline live demos](https://stackoverflow.blog/2014/09/16/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/) for years.

Comment: @quesntin see below code, I'm asking him to add css.

Comment: I am adding my css.

Answer (score 1):

Try to change this piece of code as i made:

```
<div class="col-2 col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-6">
      <div class="pc-header">
        <h2>Posts</h2>
      </div>
```

Answer (score -1):

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EITv0.png)

```css
<!-- begin snippet: js hide: false console: true babel: true -->
#prime-content {
            background-color: blue;
            margin-top: 15px;
        }

        #prime-content .sidebar-left {
            color: white;
        }

        #prime-content .sidebar-right {
            color: white;
        }

        .pc-header {
            background-color: #FFFF00;
            width: 100%;
            padding: 30px;
            text-align: center;
            margin-bottom: 10px;
        }

        .p-content {
            background-color: #fff;
            padding: 15px;
        }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <!-- The above 3 meta tags *must* come first in the head; any other head content must come *after* these tags -->
    <title>Bootstrap 101 Template</title>

    <!-- Bootstrap -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
</head>

<body style="background-color:cornflowerblue;">
    <div id="prime-content">
        <div class="container-fluid">
            <div class="row" style="margin-top:15px;">
                <div class="col-md-3 col-lg-3 col-sm-12">
                    <div class="sidebar-left text-center">
                        <h3>Degital Media Houses of Assam</h3>
                        <div class="mh-names">
                            <h4> Total no of members</h4>
                        </div>
                        <p class="mh-name"> Total no of members</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-6" style="margin-bottom:15px">
                    <div class="pc-header">
                        <h2>Posts</h2>
                    </div>
                    <div class="p-content">
                        <div class="media border">
                            <img src="https://cdn1.iconfinder.com/data/icons/avatar-2-2/512/Salesman_1-512.png" alt="Admin" class="mr-3 mt-3 rounded-circle" style="width:60px;">
                            <div class="media-body">
                                <h4>Admin <small><i>, Posted on May 19, 2018</i></small></h4>
                                <p>
                                    The JOURNALIST ASSOCIATION OF INDIA (JAI) (Non-Profit Organization) is working and fighting to protect for freedom of expression, under the valuable guidance of H K Sethi since last more than 20 years. Journalist Association of India under the flagship
                                    of Journalists Federation of India is fighting cesslessly for the Journalists... c scrutiny...
                                </p>
                                <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Read More &rarr;</a>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-3">
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Search directory">
                    <div class="sidebar-right">
                        <h3 class="text-center">Members</h3>
                        <h4 class="text-center"> Total : </h4>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Search member"><br />
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="exampleFormControlSelect1">Example select</label>
                            <div class="sort-items">
                                <select id="sort" class="form-control">
                                    <option>By Names</option>
                                    <option>Newest first</option>
                                    <option>Oldest first</option>
                                    <option>By numbers</option>
                                </select>
                            </div><br />
                            <div class="m-names">
                                <h4>1. Durlav Gogoi </h4>
                                <div style="margin-left:20px;">
                                    <p>Media House : North-East Now</p>
                                    <p>Member since : June, 2018</p>
                                    <p>Contact : Not available</p>
                                    <p>Hailed from : Sivasagar</p>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="m-names">
                                <h4>2. Rajen Sarmah </h4>
                                <div style="margin-left:20px;">
                                    <p>Media House : North-East Now</p>
                                    <p>Member since : June, 2018</p>
                                    <p>Contact : Not available</p>
                                    <p>Hailed from : Nalbari</p>
                                </div>
                            </div>

                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <!-- jQuery (necessary for Bootstrap's JavaScript plugins) -->
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <!-- Include all compiled plugins (below), or include individual files as needed -->
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

[image]

Comment: I think it is not a issue of the media queries, because I used it and also used the bootstrap grid system properly.

Comment: yes will see, upload your css in my code snippet above.

Comment: This reads more like a game of spot-the-difference-than-an-answer.

Comment: @As Dictionary check above snippet.

Comment: @Prashanth Olekar Hi thanks for this great help. It is now working fine. I have seen that my knowledge of using bootstrap's grid system was not perfect. You helped me in better understanding. But still have a question. I am using bootstrap 4 in place of your version. I noticed that my image shows the remaining white space in vertical direction instead of horizontal in your case. Besides can we reduce this white space so that text can occupy it.?

Comment: I don't know where to give the screenshot for your observation.

Comment: send your screen shot, I have used bootstrap 3.3.7 version here.

Comment: @Prashanth Olekar I am not able to find out the provision for giving the new screenshot. Where to give it? Should I do it by editing my original question? Or answering my own question?

Comment: send it to my email prashantholekar.1825@gmail.com, explain what you really need,